# How does back gating work on graphene?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, graphene

I am reading a paper in which they have increased or decreased the carrier concentration in graphene by back gating. The charges are not flowing from the gate to graphene due to oxide. Due to conservation of charge the carrier concentration in graphene should remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back gating only works if you electrically contact the graphene and then bias the gate voltage *with respect to the graphene voltage*. So you hook up a voltage source, set the graphene to ground and the gate to $+$. This is just like any RC circuit. Electrons are pulled around the circuit away from one side of the capacitor and toward the other.